# vm.provision "file" does not copy the files to the guest machine

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I wanted to copy the files from the host machine to the guest machine with

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # ... other configuration
    config.vm.provision "file", source: ".sudoers", destination: "/etc/sudoers"
    config.vm.provision "file", source: ".pacman.conf", destination: "/usr/local/etc/pacman.conf"
    config.vm.provision "file", source: ".setup.sh", destination: "/home/vagrant/setup.sh"
  end
```

But this doesn't work at all!
When doing `vagrant up` no error output is presented to me. The VM provision "file" is right between  "Mounting shared folders" and "running provisioner: shell"

[image]

If there's any info I can provide I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

- you can use a shared folder to share data between your host and your
  VM, this is the first solution .
- Else you can use the provision file like that:

```rb
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # ... other configuration
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "./sudoers", destination: "/etc/sudoers"
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "./pacman.conf", destination: "/usr/local/etc/pacman.conf"
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "./setup.sh", destination: "/home/vagrant/setup.sh"
  end
```

In your case the error is related to the path of the local files .

I hope that this help you to fix your issue.